# How can I put this following code in script tag of helmet in react JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook

I want to put the below code in the script tag of the helmet in the React JS App.

When I put this like below it showing a warning in console:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
  {`
    {
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "ProfessionalService",
    "image": [
        "image1 URL",
        "image2 URL"
        ]
    }
  `}
</script>
```

**Warning Showing in Console**

```
[Facebook Pixel] - Unable to parse JSON-LD tag. Malformed JSON found:
```

How can I remove this warning?

Comment: What are the backticks doing in there? Is that in some way part of react syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is not valid - I think you need to add a comma after "image1 url", and remove the comma after the array

Something like this should work

```
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "ProfessionalService",
    "image": [
        "image1 url",
        "image2 URL"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Sorry I already put a comma in the code but still showing warning

Comment: Have you removed the comma after the closing ']' in the array for "images" too? It's still there in your top post.

Comment: In my code, there is no comma after closing ']'